# I can upvote, but can't downvote

Tags: support, voting

On Stack Overflow, I have the privilege to upvote a question. But, I don't have it for downvoting the questions. Does the reputation differ to downvote and upvote?

Comment: _"Does the reputation differ to downvote and upvote."_ Yes it does.

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: The exact number are individual for each site, but described under [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) in each help center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check the help pages for the site the question is related to (in this case for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/)) ... i.e. the privileges part of it:

- [Vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) requires (only) rep of ***15***.
- [Vote Down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires ***125***.

Note: for meta.SE, the [privilege to vote down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) *only* requires ***100*** rep.